# How can I know which element fire the event from js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have somethings like this:

```
$('#eventFire').dblclick(function(){ 
         EventHandler.dblclickListener();
});
```

I want the `EventHandler` listen the double click event, and I want the `EventHandler` know which element from the page is fire this event, how can I do so?

Answer (score 5):

The [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) is passed as the first argument to your handler, like this:

```
$('#eventFire').dblclick(function(e){ 
  //e.target fired the event, this refers to the #eventFire element
});
```

So inside the handler, the [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) could be the element with the handler or a child (from which the even bubbled), and `this` will refer to the element the handler is on, `#eventFire` in this case.

Comment: how can I get back the #eventFire from the e??

Comment: @Tattat - Just use `e.target`, it'll be a DOM element...but it sounds like you don't want the target, you want the element you're binding to, and use `this` for that...it'll be the DOM element, use `$(this)` for a jQuery object.